# Retain/releasing memory with properties

Tags: iphone, memory-management

I have a method that gets data from the data manager.  It looks something like this:

```
- (void)GetData {
    NSArray *anArray = [datamanager GetData]; // GetData returns an autoreleased array
    self.MyDataArray = anArray;  
}
```

MyDataArray is declared as a property (nonatomic, retain)

My question is, the function datamanager GetData gets changed elsewhere in code, returning different values for anArray when GetData is called.  I'm confused at the line self.MyDataArray = anArray.  Cause as far as I know, this would retain anArray the first time, then the method GetData gets called again, then a different anArray gets retained, and so forth.  So is this a memory leak?  If so, what do I need to do in order to not have memory leaking?  thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no memory leak because MyDataArray, being declared as retain, has an implementation that releases any reference it hold before retaining the new reference when you do `self.MyDataArray = anArray`.